# Update SQL string not updating access database C#

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

This has been an interesting problems that I am having. I have used select, create table, insert, and delete sql functions in my code and they are all working fine. When i tried to get my update working It does not error out with an exception but it does not update my database either. for some background information I am using a .accdb file from access for my database which is located in my debug folder. connection string will be down below along with the code that I am using.

my connection string

```
    OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= MasterInventory.accdb");
```

code

```
          myConnection.Open();
            string searchtext = txtAssetScanned.Text;
            string searchcmd = "UPDATE " + lstCompCode.SelectedItem + " SET [Inventory Status]= 'Found' WHERE [Inventory number] LIKE '*" + searchtext + "';";
            OleDbCommand find = new OleDbCommand();
            find.Connection = myConnection;
            find.CommandText = searchcmd;
            find.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myConnection.Close();
```

side note: I know that there is sql injection in this for this project it really does not matter and I am just wanting to get it working first before completely error proofing it

Comment: If you debug your program, what actual query is composed? I suspect the `where` clause finds no fitting rows to update, are you sure you want to use `*` and not `%` ?

Comment: @HoneyBadger I had a message box that showed me the SQL statement it sent and when i Ran that same SQL statement in access it worked... Statement below UPDATE DA98 SET [Inventory Status] = 'Found' WHERE  [Inventory number] LIKE '*6055856'

Comment: So in this case `like` could be substituted with `=` and get the same result

Comment: @HoneyBadger can you use `=` with `*`? It looks like a string to me.

Comment: You'll probably need to use the percent sign (`%`) wildcard here. Queries run within Access itself usually use the asterisk (`*`), but queries from external applications use the percent sign.

Comment: @ChristopherD. Yeah it is a string, it is quoted. So why would it be a problem?

Comment: @HoneyBadger just confused about which syntax is correct when using a  connection like this. Access doesn't allow you can interchange `Like` with `=` when comparing a string containing a wildcard character. But as Gord said the syntax changes when running externally so I guess it's fine.

Comment: @HoneyBadger you were correct and that fixed it